# Bottom sheet not updating its content

Tags: flutter

Listviewbuilder is not updating when the provider updates the p variable. I want to show the circularprogressindicator while my data is not being loaded. But circularprogressindicator displays forever until I close the bottomsheet and open it again.

```
class T extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TState createState() => _TState();
}

class _TState extends State<T> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Data data = Data();
    List<P> p = Provider.of<List<P>>(context);
    Color backC = Theme.of(context).brightness != Brightness.dark
        ? data.backColorDark
        : data.backColorLight;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () async {
        await showModalBottomSheet(
          backgroundColor: backC,
          context: context,
          builder: (_) {
            return p == null
                ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                : ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: p.length,
                    itemBuilder: (_, index) => Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      child: Text(p[index].name),
                    ),
                  );
          },enter code here
        );
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, right: 20),
        child: ClayContainer(
          height: 30,
          width: 100,
          color: backC,
          borderRadius: 10,
          child: Center(child: Text('Download')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to create state full bottomsheet

Answer (score 1):

Basically, when you write the `builder` function in showModalBottomSheet, It generates a separate view for the bottom sheet. So whatever you return through `builder` will build a new view. That new view will have its own state. That's why your data is not updating there.

You have to return StatefulBuilder through `builder` function in showModalBottomSheet.

```dart
StatefulBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
        return //Your code here
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
StatefulBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
        return //Your here
    }
);
```

*Note*: Using `SetState()` inside `StatefulBuilder` has worked but if you create another method then `setState()` method would not work because `setState()` method uses `StatefulBuilder` parent class not in use by `StatefulBuilder BottomSheet` class.